# How to deploy the changes in migration to depolyed database?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

I have a `Laravel` project deployed on `AWS EB` and the database is `RDS` all things, now the database on live contains data!

The Question is: How can I deploy the changes that I made in database(migrations) then deploying them without losing the data in production database!

Note there is two things:

- if I have a new column ( I know that just create new migration then in production run `php artisan migrate`)
- If I made any change to the existing column (this is the core of my question)

Comment: You can make new migration file to change existing migration data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends of what are the changes you want to achieve.

In case to add a new column to an specific table you can always run this artisan code:

Supposing you want to create a new `role` column in `users` table:

```
php artisan make:migration add_role_to_users_table --table=users

public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->integer('role');
    });
}
```

with its respective rollback in case you want to `php artisan migrate:rollback` last steps

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->dropColumn('role');
    });
}
```

after that you just run `php artisan migrate` and updates will be made.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#rolling-back-migrations

Comment: What about I need to change the existing column in database ?

Comment: supposing that the column `role` already exists you'd have to `php artisan make:migration update_users_table --table=users` then in the newly created migration document `public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->integer('role')->change();
    });
}` and also add `down` function as shown before. Then `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: the trick with ->change() to change the column! got you, thank you!

Comment: It was my pleasure. Thanks for accepting this response as valid.